# How to get more than 20 posts Instagram API (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, pagination, instagram-api

I built a web app that renders photos from the Instagram API and I have the live token.

Wondering how I can pull more than 20 photos, I know there is the pagination but I am confused with the docs and how to actually implement this on my code

This is what I have to pull the 20 photos, how do I pull more?

```
 @response = client.get("tags/#{@tag_name}/media/recent")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the API response get the `pagination.next_url` and make API call, this will give you next 20, and then do the same until `pagination.next_url` is `null`

Comment: Can you be more specific about how to get the pagination.next_url since I am not getting that in my response and how to create the method? Thanks!

Comment: When u make the first API call: `tags/{tag_name}/media/recent`, the response will have a `data` and `pagination` items, the value of `pagination.next_url` will be the same as API URL plus a `max_id` url param value, the response from this API call will have next 20

Comment: @krisrak I double checked there is no field named pagination or next_url in response.
Any Idea that what changed?

Comment: it will not be in sandbox mode